# Is there a particularly good fork of authlogic I should use, with Rails 3 compatibility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Authlogic hasn't been updated in a few months and, while it seems to work in Rails 3, still has a ton of deprecation warnings.

Is there a particularly good fork of it I can/should use instead? I'm tempted to fork it and maintain an "authlogic-rails3" gem.

Comment: If you can, use devise in its stead

Comment: haha, well, i just want to get rid of the deprecation warnings, i don't need to reengineer my app. or is devise a drop-in replacement for authlogic?

Comment: Devise is the new hotness in Rails authentication plugins. You will need to do a little bit of rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my own, which I'm pondering naming authlogic-rails3: http://github.com/jjb/authlogic

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this and seems to be fine. https://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic/tree/rails3